# Categories mapping when migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: data-migration

Can anyone tell me whether it's possible to have a migration with categories mapping on migration for magento 1 to magento 2 and how can I do this?

Comment: categories mapping means ?

Comment: It's like: make all product from A category (source) go to B category (target). Is it clear enough to you?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can migrate your categories and can custom to map your categories from Magento 1 to the right place on Magento 2. If you are looking for a service to do this for you, let me know so we can discuss further!

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I got successfully the migration process.